# Android Studio: Facing an error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am running Android Studio with my firewall settings on which is leading me to the following error:
Internal HTTP Server disabled:Cannot start internal HTTP server.Git Integration, JavaScript debugger and LiveEdit may operate with errors. Please check your firewall settings and restart Android Studio.
How to resolve the error.

[image]

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Allow Android Studio advanced network access through your firewall:

Open control panel, search for "firewall," and click "Windows Firewall."

In the left pane, click "Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall:"

[image: Left pane of Firewall]

Click Change settings.  Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

Select the check box next to the program you want to allow, select the network locations you want to allow communication on, and then click OK.

Source: [microsoft's documentation.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communicate-through-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7)